# Use of future reserved word in strict mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

I am trying to define an array on es6 and I am getting `Use of future reserved word in strict mode`. This is my attempt:

```
 {let colours = ["green","yellow","red"]}
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Why do you have curly braces around it?

Comment: I have curly braces because I am trying to define the array in reactJS file

Comment: You cannot define variables inside `.jsx` expressions. Define your array outside of the return statement and reference it in the expression: `let colours = ["green","yellow","red"]` and then later `{ colours }` The use of `let` is what is causing that error inside of strict mode. Change it to `var`. Sounds like you're in an es2015 env. Or you could transpile your code with something like babel: https://babeljs.io/

Comment: @Kyle you got the right solution for the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of `let` is what is causing that error inside of strict mode. Change it to `var`. Sounds like you're in an es2015 env. Or you could transpile your code with something like [babel](https://babeljs.io/).

You also cannot define variables inside .jsx expressions. Define your array outside of the return statement and reference it in the expression: `let colours = ["green","yellow","red"]` and then later `{ colours }`.